# Как правильно составить конструктор копирования для Stack

Tags: c++, c++11

чисто для себя пытаюсь написать Stack и возникла такая проблема, возможно ли как-то избавится от вектора в конструкторе и операторах присваивания? Как это правильно сделать? Ну и если не затрудни, укажите на ошибки если таковые имеются и что бы вы изменили.

```
#ifndef _STACK_H_
#define _STACK_H_
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
class Stack
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Type Element;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };
    int count = 0;
    Node* tail;
public:
    Stack();
    Stack(const Stack & stk);
    Stack(Stack && stk);
    Stack & operator = (const Stack & stk);
    Stack & operator = (Stack && stk);
    std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os) const;
    ~Stack();

    void push(Type val);
    void pop();
    bool empty() const;
    void show() const;
    std::optional<Type> top() const;
    size_t size() const;
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Stack<Type>::Stack() : tail(nullptr)
{

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Stack<Type>::Stack(const Stack & stk) : tail(nullptr)
{
    std::vector<Type> tmp;
    for (Node* n_ptr = stk.tail; n_ptr != nullptr; n_ptr = n_ptr->next)
    {
        tmp.push_back(n_ptr->Element);
    }

    for (auto it = tmp.rbegin(); it != tmp.rend(); ++it)
    {
        Node* n_ptr_new = new Node;
        n_ptr_new->Element = *it;
        n_ptr_new->next = tail;
        tail = n_ptr_new;
    }
    count = tmp.size();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Stack<Type>::Stack(Stack && stk) : count(stk.count), tail(stk.tail)
{
    stk.count = 0;
    stk.tail = nullptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Stack<Type> & Stack<Type>::operator = (const Stack & stk)
{
    if (this == &stk)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    while (tail)
    {
        Node* temp = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    count = 0;

    std::vector<Type> temp;
    for (Node* n_ptr = stk.tail; n_ptr != nullptr; n_ptr = n_ptr->next)
    {
        temp.push_back(n_ptr->Element);
    }

    for (auto it = temp.rbegin(); it != temp.rend(); ++it)
    {
        Node* n_ptr_new = new Node;
        n_ptr_new->Element = *it;
        n_ptr_new->next = tail;
        tail = n_ptr_new;
    }
    count = tmp.size();
    return *this;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Stack<Type> & Stack<Type>::operator = (Stack && stk)
{
    if (this == &stk)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<Type> temp;
    for (Node* n_ptr = stk.tail; n_ptr != nullptr; n_ptr = n_ptr->next)
    {
        temp.push_back(n_ptr->Element);
    }

    while (stk.tail)
    {
        Node* temp = stk.tail;
        stk.tail = stk.tail->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    stk.count = 0;

    while (tail)
    {
        Node* temp = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    count = 0;

    for (auto it = temp.rbegin(); it != temp.rend(); ++it)
    {
        Node* n_ptr_new = new Node;
        n_ptr_new->Element = *it;
        n_ptr_new->next = tail;
        tail = n_ptr_new;
    }
    count = tmp.size();
    return *this;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Stack<Type>::~Stack()
{
    while (tail)
    {
        Node* temp = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    count = 0;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
template <typename Type>
void Stack<Type>::push(Type val)
{
    Node* n_ptr = new Node;
    n_ptr->Element = val;
    count++;
    n_ptr->next = tail;
    tail = n_ptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Stack<Type>::pop()
{
    Node* n_ptr = tail;
    tail = tail->next;
    count--;
    delete n_ptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Stack<Type>::show() const
{
    if (empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Stack is empty! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (Node* ptr = tail; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next)
        {
            std::cout << ptr->Element << " \n";
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
std::optional<Type> Stack<Type>::top() const
{
    if (!empty())
    {
        return tail->Element;
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
size_t Stack<Type>::size() const
{
    return count;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
bool Stack<Type>::empty() const
{
    return tail == nullptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
std::ostream & Stack<Type>::operator << (std::ostream & os) const
{
    return os;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif // STACK_H_
```

Comment: Если вы посмотрите стандарт stl, std::stack, то увидите, что там можно задавать контейнер, с помощью которого будут храниться элементы стэка, и по сути std::stack это интерфейс LIFO, реализованный над подходящим контейнером. То есть в stl по дефолту стэк - это двусвязный список. И в конструкторе копирования  стэк просто копирует контейнер другого стэка. То есть Вам для начала надо сделать свой двусвсязный список на шаблонах, а потом уже поверх него писать стэк.  А у вас получается стэк это и стэк и односвязный список одновременно

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы, буду реализовывать через двусвязный список.

Comment: Непонятно, как принимались решения о том, где для полей класса использовать новый синтаксис с инициализатором, а где - классическую инициализацию в конструкторе. Почему `int count = 0;`, но при этом `Node* tail;` инициализируется дальше в конструкторе. В чем тут идея?

Comment: @AnT Не внимательность. По ходу создания класса обнулил счётчик и забыл про него. Благодарю за исправление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Избавиться от вектора никакого труда не составит. Никакого двусвязного списка для этого не нужно

  ```
  template <typename Type>
  Stack<Type>::Stack(const Stack & stk)
  {
    Node **pnext = &tail;

    for (const Node *n_ptr = stk.tail; n_ptr != nullptr; n_ptr = n_ptr->next)
    {
      Node *n_ptr_new = new Node(*n_ptr);
      *pnext = n_ptr_new;
      pnext = &n_ptr_new->next;
      ++count;
    }

    *pnext = nullptr;

    assert(count == stk.count);
  }
  ```
- В реализации вашего *копирующего* оператора присваивания стоило бы воспользоваться идиомой copy-and-swap, вместо того, чтобы по второму разу переписывать код конструктора копирования и деструктора

  ```
  template <typename Type>
  Stack<Type> & Stack<Type>::operator = (const Stack & stk)
  {
    if (this == &stk)
      return *this;

    Stack copy(stk);
    std::swap(tail, copy.tail);
    std::swap(count, copy.count);

    return *this;
  }
  ```
- Что за ужас у вас понаписан в *перемещающем* операторе присваивания - вообще не понятно. Ваш перемещающий оператор присваивания по сути занимается полноценным копированием. Но зачем он такой нужен, если у вас уже есть копирующий оператор присваивания??? Если уж вы взялись писать перемещающий оператор присваивания, то *перемещайте*, а не копируйте. Например, один из возможных вариантов реализации - просто `swap`

  ```
  template <typename Type>
  Stack<Type> & Stack<Type>::operator = (Stack && stk)
  {
    std::swap(tail, stk.tail);
    std::swap(count, stk.count);
    return *this;
  }
  ```
- И, если самоприсваивание не является частой ситуацией в вашем коде, то оба оператора присваивания (копирующий и перемещающий) можно будет слить в один

  ```
  template <typename Type>
  Stack<Type> & Stack<Type>::operator = (Stack stk)
  {
    std::swap(tail, copy.tail);
    std::swap(count, copy.count);
    return *this;
  }
  ```

  (обратите внимание на передачу параметра *по значению*).

  В ситуациях, допускающих перемещение (`a = std::move(b)`), такое присваивание будет выливаться в вызов конструктора перемещения (из `b` в `stk`), за которым последует обмен внутри оператора присваивания, и деструкция `stk` (вместо со "старыми" данными из `a`).

  В ситуациях, требующих копирования (`a = b`), такое присваивание будет выливаться в вызов конструктора копирования (из `b` в `stk`), за которым последует обмен внутри оператора присваивания, и деструкция `stk` (вместо со "старыми" данными из `a`).
- Ваш оператор вывода `<<` написан так, что ваш стек будет у него первым (левым) аргументом, а поток - вторым (правым). Это весьма неожиданный синтаксис для операции вывода - все задом-наперед. Традиционно первым аргументом является именно поток. Но привычный традиционный вариант невозможно перегрузить методом класса. Такая перегрузка может быть сделана только отдельностоящей функцией (например, friend-функцией).

Comment: Ох. Спасибо за все поправки. И правда в операторе перемещения присваиванием был полный ужас. Буду сейчас во все это вникать. Но со сливанием операторов в один не до конца понял(первый раз вижу такую реализацию) особенно про **перемещающий конструктор копирования**. Я эти операторы вообще реализовывал для того, что бы понять как они работают. Теперь с вашим объяснением стало нагляднее.

Comment: @Sunny Stealth: "Перемещающий конструктор копирования" - это мой косяк. Правильно: **конструктор перемещения**. Исправил.

Comment: А этот кусок не считается конструктором перемещения?

    template <typename Type>
    Stack<Type>::Stack(Stack && stk) : count(stk.count), tail(stk.tail)
    {
        stk.count = 0;
        stk.tail = nullptr;
    }

Comment: @Sunny Stealth: Ой, не заметил. Считается конечно. Исправляю ответ. С конструктором перемещения у вас все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Если не использовать вектор, то можно реализовать это через динамический массив. Иначе больше никак. В противном случае скопированный стек будет идти в обратном порядке. Либо реализовывать его на базе двусвязного списка, как уже предложили. В таком случае можно будет обойтись без дополнительных буферов.